# Is it possible for a web page to log your keystrokes?

Tags: chrome, keyloggers

Is it possible to have a web page in Chrome open, and it can run a web app of sorts on the webpage, and have that web page log your keystrokes?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to implement a keylogger in javascript but it's scope is limited to the web page it loaded from because javascript limits the impact of itself to the web page. Sometimes there are exploits that enable an attacker to break out of the js sandbox and can affect a wider scope.

Anyway js can be included by an attacker through XSS or a MITM attack to capture what the vicitim is typing. So an attacker could target your credentials or the webapps chat (if there is one) for example.

This is why they tell you not to include your js unencrypted. It enables MITM attackers to inject js into an otherwise encrypted connection.

If your intereseted in how this works in detail you can have a look [here](http://michaelhendrickx.com/201106-jqlog-jquery-keylogger.html).

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work, in reality javascript is not that secure and exploits to leave the sandbox of the webpage exist.

Comment: I extended my answer to respect the fact that there can be exploits to break out of the sandbox

Answer (score 2):

If you can bypass the **Same Origin Policy** of the browser your javascript will be able to execute the key logger in any opened webpage if you break the sandbox you will be able to do it in the OS.

On the other hand if you manage to do that you should contact google as they usually offer prices around 50k to someone that breaks the security of the browser... :)

Other option is run or install the keylogger as a browser add on or active X application, but for that you will need to accept and trust the application or install it, so you need to really click in lots of yes and ignore lots of warnings...

I don't know if modern browsers even make that question anymore or just simply ignore the application execution request by default.

Answer (score 1):

I read something similar to [this article](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/07/how-the-way-you-type-can-shatter-anonymity-even-on-tor/) the other day. Basically sites can capture keystrokes in js like others have said, but in this case they are using that information to profile you as a user and not necessarily for logging keystrokes to collect what you type.